Append an existing text file to one just created in VBA Excel
There are posts here about appending text generated through Excel to an existing text file. I want to do the opposite.
I grab a few cells from my Excel table and then I would like to append a large amount of static text (let's call it a footer) to this new content.
Sub ExportForSTK()
Dim myFile As String, TargetName As String, rng As Range, i As Integer
Dim Target(2) As String
    For i = 1 To 2 'temporary for working this out
    TargetName = ActiveSheet.Range("B5")
    Filename = TargetName & i & ".t"
    Val1= ActiveSheet.Range("F5")
    Val2 = ActiveSheet.Range("G5")
    ' ... etc.
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "Filename.txt"
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, TextOutput(i)
    'Add contents of footer.txt to the end of Filename.txt
    Close #1
Next i

I'm missing the big bit about appending footer.txt to Filename.txt.
I tried copy pasting footer.txt into the code directly but it's full of quotes and I didn't want to hassle with escaping them all.

If 32k or less you could paste the content into a worksheet cell and read it from there.

Based on your original code, here is the code you need. It uses a text stream object to hold the contents of the footer text file. You could consider converting all your file i/o to use the FileStreamObject. Would also recommend the use of the FreeFile function which returns the next available file number.
See:
Link to: Text Stream Object
Link to: OpenTextFile Method
Link to: File System Object
Sub ExportForSTK()

Dim myFile As String, TargetName As String, rng As Range, i As Integer
Dim Target(2) As String

Dim strFooterText As String
Dim fso As Object, tso As Object
Dim intFileNumber As Integer

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

    ' Get the footer text from the text file one time only
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set tso = fso.OpenTextFile(Application.DefaultFilePath & "\Footer.txt", ForReading, True, TristateFalse)
    strFooterText = tso.ReadAll
    tso.Close

    For i = 1 To 2 'temporary for working this out
    TargetName = ActiveSheet.Range("B5")
    FileName = TargetName & i & ".t"
    Val1 = ActiveSheet.Range("F5")
    Val2 = ActiveSheet.Range("G5")
    ' ... etc.
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\Filename.txt"
    intFileNumber = FreeFile
    
    Open myFile For Output As #intFileNumber
    
    Print #intFileNumber, TextOutput(i)
    Print #intFileNumber, strFooterText

    Close #intFileNumber
Next i

Set tso = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub

